# Étymologie québécoise

Tags: étymologie, québec

Y a-t-il une référence sur l'étymologie des mots utilisés au Québec mais pas en France (pas pour le même sens en tout cas).

Exemple avec un *piton*, qui fait tout de suite référence (pour moi, français, en tout cas) à un piton rocheux et dont mon [dictionnaire étymologique](http://www.puf.com/wiki/Quadrige_dicos_poche%3aDictionnaire_%C3%A9tymologique_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) donne

> un dérivé d'un radical *pïtt-* répandu dans les langues romanes et désignant quelque chose de pointu.

Comment ce mot a-t-il pu finir par désigner au Québec un bouton ou une touche sur les appareils modernes (touches qui sont loin d'être pointues) et même donner le verbe *pitonner* pour appuyer sur un bouton ?

Utilisés par l'Assemblée nationale du Québec, je présume qu'ils sont bien ancrés dans la langue et admis pour être utilisés avec ces nouveaux sens.

> *C’est-à-dire qu’au lieu de l'écrire à la main il va le pitonner.*
>   (Assemblée nationale du Québec, Journal des débats, Commission permanente de l’agriculture, des pêcheries et de l’alimentation, 16 février 1993)

Comment: Je suis québécois, j'aime l'étymologie, mais j'en ai aucune idée. Je suis curieux de lire les réponses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La référence est probablement *Le Dictionnaire historique du français québécois : monographies lexicographiques des québécismes (DHFQ)*. Il a été écrit par [l'équipe du TLFQ](http://www.tlfq.ulaval.ca/presentation/). Je crains qu'il ne soit un peu daté maintenant.

Un compte-rendu de lecture du dictionnaire est disponible [ici](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~wulfric/articles/utq/utq1999.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Malheureusement je n'ai pas trouvé non plus l'étymologie de piton.

Cet [article wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) offre une liste de mots ou expressions québécoises avec leurs équivalents en Europe avec des exemples. Il y a aussi une liste d'anglicismes ou de mots qui proviennent de l'ancien français. Mise à part la deuxième liste qui décrit brièvement l'origine des termes, tu n'apprendras pas beaucoup sur l'étymologie pour la plupart de nos expressions mais, c'est néanmois une bonne référence pour les comprendre et trouver leurs équivalents.

Answer (score 3):

> Comment ce mot [*piton* :  [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/piton/61223), [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/piton), [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/99657) ] a-t-il pu finir par désigner au Québec un bouton ou une
>   touche sur les appareils modernes (touches qui sont loin d'être
>   pointues) et même donner le verbe pitonner pour appuyer sur un bouton
>   ?

C'est la chose pointue et, par extension, *la petite chose* (quoique aussi familièrement, de manière populaire, le *nez proéminent*) ; c'est par analogie avec la forme de la tête **en anneau** de la vis qu'on a *piton* pour bouton, devenu fort usuel depuis la fin des années 1970 ; et avec la locution *être sur le piton* (en forme), c'est attesté en 1930 au Québec (DHLF/2012). Un ouvrage comme le [*Glossaire du parler français au Canada*](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf), préparé par la [Société du parler français du Canada](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_du_parler_fran%C3%A7ais_au_Canada), éd. *L'action sociale*, 1930, est une référence importante, et on y trouve sept (7) éléments pour piton, dont le bouton (de... sonnette, galerie, montre, toupie) où l'on réfère à la forme en anneau de la tête du clou...

---

Souvent on traite du verbe dérivé, *pitonner*, dans le contexte plus restreint d'une comparaison avec [*zapper*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873551), et le [saute-chaîne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapping), et on parle [parfois](https://books.google.com/books?id=wPP_K4_n6rQC&lpg=PA167&dq=piton%20fran%C3%A7ais%20qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q=piton%20fran%C3%A7ais%20qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois&f=false) de *pianoter*, [ou familièrement de](https://books.google.com/books?id=RdoCGQM6rbIC&lpg=PA97&dq=piton%20fran%C3%A7ais%20qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q=piton%20fran%C3%A7ais%20qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois&f=false) *tapoter sur*, *d'actionner les touches de*..., *saisir* (un code etc.), mais l'emploi du piton est plus vaste et n'est pas non plus consigné au bouton au Québec. Diverses [raisons](https://books.google.com/books?id=XKXZ5Lzm1N8C&lpg=PA24&dq=piton%20fran%C3%A7ais%20qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=piton&f=false) peuvent expliquer pourquoi un québécisme reste compréhensible ou non pour un locuteur qui n'est pas familier avec cette variété du français...

---

On peut aller assez loin même sans les ressources [spécialisées](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/351), et un ouvrage comme le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. *Robert*, 2012 (tout comme le *Larousse* et le *TLFi* en ligne, comme on le voit ici) se penche aussi sur cette variété du français alors qu'on y parle à l'entrée *pitonner* de développement parallèle basé sur le sens québécois du piton ; on identifie même un truc assez difficile comme le *pitonneux*, dans le sens de la *télécommande* ou génériquement de l'objet sur lequel on pitonne (à mon avis la personne qui pitonne pourrait aussi être ainsi qualifiée, comme avec le [*patenteux*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/patenteux/58619?q=patenteux#693791), l'inventeur).