# Quelles sont les principales différences entre le français québecois et le français de France?

Tags: québec, france

Je pourrais visiter le Québec dans peu de temps.  Quelles sont les erreurs fréquents à ne pas commettre concernant le français québecois ?  Par "erreurs", je ne veux pas dire les choses simplement rares, mais les choses dans le français de France qui sembleraient incompréhensibles pour les québecois, ou au moins très bizarres.

Comment: Voir aussi [Etymologie québécoise](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/350)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quelques exemples amusants :

1. Ne parle pas de tes **gosses** (qui désigne là-bas les testicules), pour parler de tes enfants, utilise **flos** (ou simplement enfants ;) )
2. ne t'offusque pas si on te demande si tu as vu un **bibite** (c'est un insecte)
3. **Chauffer** une voiture signifie conduire une voiture
4. Si on te dis que tu es **épais**, tu peux te vexer, en gros on te traite d'idiot.
5. **Etre bourré** ne signifie pas être saoûl, mais simplement avoir trop mangé
6. si on te propose une **liqueur** tôt le matin, n'aie crainte, il s'agit juste d'une boisson gazeuse
7. enfin, si on te propose une **turlutte**, ne soit pas choqué (ou pas), il s'agira en fait d'une petite chanson.

J'ai trouvé une liste assez [complète chez Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois)

Comment: [Quand plus rien ne va / Que tout ne va pas / Quand plus rien n'est droit / Que tout est de guingois / On peut essayer de souffler dans un joli roseau percé / Jouer un petit air de flûte / Ou bien faire une petite turlutte](http://www.chansons-paroles.com/Mes-souliers-sont-rouges-1191/Quand-plus-rien-ne-va-Turlutte-16203.htm)

Comment: Make sure to brush up on "les mots sacrés" in the [wikipedia article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_(juron)).  Swearing is quite different in Québec.

Comment: @Zoot the term is "les sacres" (swear words), not "les mots sacrés" (dsacred words).

Answer (score 2):

As a visitor to Canada, nobody will expect you to know the ins and outs of Canadian French, or even really to make much of an attempt to speak Canadian French. They won't have any problem talking to you even if the target variety of French that you've been learning is European French.

The differences between Quebec French and European French are obviously too numerous to list, so all I can do is give you a couple of rules of thumb.

With that said, there are some things that you can do to reduce misunderstandings. In general, the likelihood of not being understood is the highest when using the following kinds of words:

1. Informal words like *clope*, *godasse*, *choper*, and so on. Instead, use words of a neutral register to make yourself understood: *cigarette*, *chaussure*, *attraper*. Canadian and European French do of course share many words of an informal register, but this is still the area where the divergence is greatest for a learner.
2. French realia like *lycée* or *SAMU*. Instead, use geographically neutral terms like *école secondaire* or *ambulance*.

Lastly, if you need to check if a particular term will be understood in Quebec, look it up in a dictionary such as *Dictionnaire québécois d'aujourd'hui* or Merriam-Webster's French-Englsh dictionary. or online at usito.usherbrooke.ca. All three of these dictionaries have labels for words or senses specific to European French (such as "France", "surtout en France" or "F/E"). *Usito* has particularly extensive coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Pour vous aider, voici deux projets web qui listent les différences entre le français de France et le français québécois :

- [www.je-parle-quebecois.com](http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com) est un projet qui s'amuse avec l'usage de la langue française au Québec et au Canada. Il y a des vidéos, des contenus et des illustrations pour présenter les termes québécois. Ce projet demeure un site de divertissement qui s'adresse à tous les curieux.
- Il y a aussi [www.japprendslequebecois.com](https://www.japprendslequebecois.com) qui prend la forme d'une méthode d'apprentissage complète et structurée. Elle est destinée à ceux qui ont besoin de comprendre la structure, les sonorités et toutes les subtilités du français québécois.

J'espère que vous apprécierez ces projets, à bientôt.

Answer (score -1):

Honnêtement, il n'y a plus grand expression française qui m'étonne, il y a beaucoup de français au Québec de nos jours, je ne m'en ferais pas trop avec ça si j'étais toi!