# The French spoken in Canada vs. the French spoken in France

Tags: québec, comparaison-de-langues, france

What are the differences between Canada's French and France's French?
Should I study a little bit of both? Are there some words or expressions from one that might not be understood by the other?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad a question for this site. It's dialectology.

Comment: @Lambie This is a question people often ask so it attracts people to the site. Its text asks for some specifics. Canadian French doesn't need to be set aside to discuss those other varieties you mention. At the present there are more questions about QC/Canadian French than those varieties. Plus an answer from Louisiana has just been bountied.

Comment: @escarlateadamantine On other language sites, *they don't allow questions like this*. They are too broad and cannot be answered so easily. I wonder how many people have heard the French spoken in Chéticamp? It ain't no Québecois, that I can guarantee you.  And it's fascinating.  French-speaking Africa has a lot of slang (depending on the country) and is quasi-creolized in some places. In others, it sounds just like Paris. I am not a specialist in dialectology but it's interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the differences between Canada's French and France's French?

Written and formal types of French are very similar. There are only a few cosmetic and vocabulary differences that do not prevent mutual comprehension. For example, I just read the Radio Canada news web page, and the only word that wouldn't have been used in a similar page from French media is that title: *Est-ce vrai que les tomates ne goûtent plus rien?* Here the verb *goûter* is used a way unknown to academic French which only document *goûter* as "someone tastes something" and never "something tastes something" so it would heve been *Est-ce vrai que les tomates n'ont plus de goût ?* here. That didn't prevent at all my understanding first because I already guessed this meaning after hearing it first in Belgian French a while ago, and second because whatever verb used, the context makes clear what it means so this would have equally work: *Est-ce vrai que les tomates ne schtroumpfent plus rien ?* ;-)

Spoken French can be an issue. Colloquial conversations between French Canadians (see [joual](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joual)) might be unintelligible to France native speakers and sometimes subtitles are used in Quebec movies available in France. I suspect the opposite might be less of an issue because Canadian French-speakers have probably more exposure to French from France, its accents and expressions than the other way around.

On the other hand, I have never had any real issue understanding and being understood when meeting French Canadians, only occasional unexpected vocabulary, gender, familiarity (*tu* vs *vous*) and expressions issues that are quickly sorted out. I carefully watched the video about the *[tomates qui ne goûtent plus rien](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/info/videos/media-8442883/est-ce-vrai-que-tomates-ne-goutent-plus-rien)* and I can confirm everything was 100% understandable to me. I just had to stay more concentrated than usual because of the difference between the accents I'm used to hear and the accents of the people speaking in that video.

> Should I study a little bit of both?

That's up to you.

> Are there some words or expressions from one that might not be understood by the other?

Yes, probably a similar level of misunderstanding that would occur between US and UK English speakers.

Comment: De plus, combien de temps un(e) Français(e) faut-il passer à se familiariser avec les accents Québécois en s’y immergeant?

Comment: @FrankScience Il faudrait demander à quelqu'un qui a plus d'expérience que moi sur la question. Les différences d'accents et de grammaire sont probablement beaucoup plus rapides à assimiler que celles concernant le vocabulaire et les expressions spécifiques qui doivent être entendus pour être acquis. Le taux d'exposition et les capacités de mémorisation de la personne en question seront bien sûr aussi des facteurs importants.

Comment: Il faut noter, comme l'indique le lien wikipédia, que le joual n'est qu'un des sociolectes parlés au Québec. Le joual n'est pas le language courant ou familier au Québec, mais il peut l'avoir influencé. Le joual est d'origine urbaine et toute difficulté associée aux variétés régionales y est peu ou pas reliée. Souvent on s'attarde à un parler hautement basilectal qu'on présente comme un standard et avec lequel on a certaines difficultés. Si on écoute [René Lévesque](https://youtu.be/rQLN3WejR9U) il y a 50+ années, on serait fort étonné qu'on comprenne moins de 99% de ce qui est dit. Merci !

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Oui, bien sûr, il n'existe pas **un** français du Canada pas plus qu'il n'existe **un** français de France, Belgique, etc. René Lévesque parle ici un français « standard » dénué de régionalisme et parfaitement compréhensible en France. Il fait cependant allusion au joual (ou à un joual) en parlant de *broche à foin*, ce qui prouve donc qu'il est « bilingue » et conscient de la pluralité des niveaux de langages au Québec. Une autre originalité de son discours vis à vis d'homme politiques français de 1962 et même contemporains est sa prononciation bien meilleure de l'anglais.

Comment: Bien j'entends le Québec dans son parler mais pour l'essentiel je suis d'accord avec vous. Pour son anglais bien il le parlait très jeune d'après mes souvenirs parce qu'il est né en Gaspésie, à New Carlisle, bonne observation ! Merci.

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Maître Yoda tu es ? ;-)

Comment: Une autre bonne observation ! :)

Comment: @FrankScience: Pour ce qui est de s'immerger, le point crucial est **les** accents québecois. Pour ce qui se parle à montréal, en quelques semaines on s'y fait, et comme dit jlliagre, *tu-vs-vous* et les expressions les plus fréquentes (*Merci - Bienvenue*), c'est trivial (donc disons un mois immergé pour l'adopter). Si on s'éloigne de la ville et qu'on va dans la campagne *creuse*, et plus on se rapproche du véritable joual, et plus la langue se différencie, plus l'accent devient marqué, et là ça prend plus de temps et d'entrainement de l'oreille. C'est très comparable au chti, cf le film.

Answer (score 9):

This is a multi-part question, and I'm mostly going to focus on your second question about which variety you should aim to learn, and broaden it to include how one could go about learning Canadian French.

With respect to passive mastery of French, you will naturally learn whatever you are exposed to, so my answer will mostly address the question of which variety to aim to use when you speak. This is important because the patterns of speech you adopt when you learn a second language are quite hard to undo, so it is likely that whichever dialect you aim for first will remain dominant for you, even as you progress to far higher levels of ability.

I think it's fair to say that the Parisian variety of French can be regarded as a standard for all French-speakers outside of North America, both native speakers in Europe and non-native ones elsewhere. If you listen to a Belgian or Swiss newscast, you will hear relatively few differences in accent and vocabulary with France. And as time goes on, those differences are becoming fewer among the educated general population. Within France, my observations are that non-Parisian accents are seldom heard in national broadcasts, though educated speakers from the south of France often do have a regional accent.

In Canada, on the other hand, you have a situation where formal registers of the language are distancing themselves across the board from European French and incorporating non-European features of the usage of the educated middle class of Quebec. At the same time, with increasing levels of schooling, the lowest registers are moving closer to the speech of the educated and hence to the standard. The sociolinguistic changes of the last fifty years or so in Quebec in fact closely parallel those that have taken place in Australian English in relation to British English. (There used to be a quasi-British *Cultivated Australian* accent, but it is no longer heard.)

Assuming that you are from a country outside the French-speaking world, and that you don't have any reason to expect to have closer connections with French Canada than with the rest of the French-speaking world, it is difficult to recommend in good conscience that you aim to speak Canadian French. I can see three main reasons:

(1) Numerically, francophone Canadians are just over 10% of native speakers. France: about 57 million, Canada: 7.5 million, Belgium: about 4 million, Switzerland: 1.6 million.

(2) As a practical matter, it is diffcult to find teachers outside Canada and pedagogical materials that teach Canadian French (but more on this below).

(3) In my experience, many people in France (perhaps a sizable minority) harbour a degree of prejudice towards those who speak with non-Parisian accents, particularly including those from Quebec and the south of France. They may make unwarranted assumptions about a person's intelligence and education based on accent. I have met people from both the north and south of France who felt tremendous social pressure to abandon their regional accents. The result is that most educated northerners have adopted Parisian accents (or something close), while those in the south mostly retain their accents and weather the inevitable prejudices they face if they move north or otherwise deal with northerners. Though few speakers of Quebec French live in France, my sense is that the few who do are likely to face similar accent discrimination.

These attitudes towards Quebec French extend beyond France and seem also to be present to a degree among second-language speakers elsewhere (such as in former French colonies), where learners, in the course of studying French, may have been exposed to the pervasive ideology of the standard associated with the French language everywhere.

If, on the other hand, you expect that your contact with French-speakers will primarily be with Canadians, then it is sensible to aim to approximate the usage of educated francophone Quebecers (though if you are outside Canada, the practical challenges in doing this should not be underestimated).

I would like to emphasize that anglophone and allophone Canadians who are starting out in French will gain nothing by aiming for a European variety on the basis that it is the "standard". To French Canadians, you will sound anglophone until you lose your English accent; if you are fortunate enough to lose your English accent, you will merely come across as a foreign francophone, but not necessarily as any more articulate than if you spoke Quebec French. French Canadians don't dislike European French, but they do feel it is inappropriate when spoken *by Canadians*. (In the same way, Americans may love listening to a Tony Blair speak, but could they instinctively accept someone born in Topeka who spoke that way as American?)

I can illustrate this by recalling the 2011 federal election. Michael Ignatieff and Jack Layton both spoke passable French, and both made the kinds of mistakes anglophones typically make. But they also made other kinds of "mistakes." Ignatieff, on various occasions, elicited ridicule by using European French words like *des baskets* (instead of the expected  *espadrilles*, "running shoes"). This perfectly fit the existing narrative of him being "out of touch". Layton, on the other hand, sometimes used forms of speech strongly associated with the Quebec working class. Though these would have been considered illiteracies on the part of a francophone politician, French Canadians often considered them charming coming out of Layton's mouth.

So, considering that the vast majority of learning materials have Parisian French as the target variety, how can you acquire Canadian French? Here are some ideas.

(1) If at all possible, try to get a teacher or conversation partner who is a speaker of Canadian French. This should be easy if you're in Canada, but may be difficult elsewhere.

(2) If you are in Canada, seek out group activities in French. How many kids across the country attend French immersion but have zero contact with the local francophone minorities?

(2') If you're American and are learning French very seriously because of your French Canadian or Acadian heritage, you should strongly consider opportunities for immersion in Quebec (if you're from New England) or New Brunswick (if you're from Louisiana). You'll discover that there are thriving communities there that live their everyday lives in a beautiful, vibrant French very much like that once spoken in your communities, but which you may now only hear echoes of in the oldest community members.

(3) Consume Canadian French-language media as much as possible. If you listen to Radio-Canada's *Première Chaîne* radio, which I believe can be streamed around the world, you will mostly hear middle-class Quebec French.

(4) When you start to work seriously on pronunciation, learn the detailed rules of Canadian French. Douglas Walker's *The Pronunciation of Canadian French* is excellent for this.

(5) Even before you start working hard on making your accent more native, pay close attention to the vowel pairs that are distinguished by Canadians but never or not always by Parisians. You'll find the theory in Walker's book, but the distinctions that are not systematically reflected in contemporary European French dictionaries are: *espace*/*place* [ɛspɑ:s]/[plas], *baisse*/*laisse* [bɛ:s]/[lɛs]. Other important distinctions not always observed in Parisian French but which are still faithfully reflected in European dictionaries are *fait*/*fée* [ɛ]/[e], *brin*/*brun* [ɛ̃]/[œ̃], *jeune*/*jeûne* [œ]/[ø]. (Though this is seldom mentioned in reference works, I also find the *blanc*/*blond* [blɑ̃]/[blɔ̃] distinction to be muddled in the speech of increasing numbers of European francophones.)

If you learn thousands of words without paying attention to these distinctions, the words will be very hard to "unlearn." A good reference for the Canadian pronunciation of vocabulary words is the online Usito dictionary (usito.usherbrooke.ca). In fact, this is a good all-round dictionary that carefully distinguishes between words and senses that are specific to Canada (marked "Q/C"), those that are specific to Europe ("F/E") and those that are common to the two (hence unmarked).

(6) Have a good selection of reference works on Canadian French available. I can recommend:

- *Dictionnaire Usito* (online only)
- *Dictionnaire québécois d'aujourd'hui* (Le Robert)
- *The Merriam-Webster French Dictionary*
- *Dictionnaire des Canadianismes*, by Gaston Dulong
- *NTC's Dictionary of Canadian French*, by Robinson and Smith
- *Base de données lexicographiques panfrancophone* (online)
- *Grammaire québécoise d'aujourd'hui*, by Jean-Marcel Léard
- *The Pronunciation of Canadian French*, by Douglas Walker
- *Nos façons de parler*, by Denis Dumas
- *Les Prononciations du francais québécois : normes et usages*, bu Ostiguy and Tousignant
- There are also specific works on Acadian French, but I don't know them well.

Lastly, I'd like to point out that even if a person immigrates to Quebec speaking European French or something like it, the vast majority of Quebecers will be respectful of them. However, they will also continue to be perceived by many as foreign in a certain sense. French Quebecers do enjoy hearing immigrants who speak Quebec French, even if they continue to make non-native mistakes.

Comment: A deep grasp of the question, wonderfully documented by numerous invaluable facts, and in the end, an ideal point of view, the point of view anyone  shouldn't hesitate to make theirs and trust as reliable.

Comment: I doubt  that " in former French colonies" spend much time worrying much about Canadian French. Canadian French speakers seem unaware the wealth of French accents and varieties found around the globe. There's French in Oceania (New Caledonia, among others), there's French in the Indian Ocean (Mauritius, Reunion Island, for example), there's French in Guiana (Latin America). And the "crown jewel": Africa.

Comment: Where: Selon une estimation de l'Organisation internationale de la Francophonie de 2014, **54,7 % des 212 millions de locuteurs quotidiens du français dans le monde (soit 116 millions) se situent en Afrique**. AND: Dans chacun des pays francophones d'Afrique **le français est parlé avec des spécificités locales pour ce qui est de la prononciation et du vocabulaire**. [Correctiontion: people spend much time]

Comment: Oh, well, history matters too; so there were those colonies called [_Nouvelle-France_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_France) you see, and Canada ([Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec)) is really the last stronghold of the French language in North-America, so that's meaningful. Plus that colony and what ensued, that was really instrumental in shaping what North-America, and the United-States, are like today. In a country like Canada with its linguistic duality and official bilingualism [and all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_identity), its immigration data...

Comment: and [policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_to_Canada), it's rather likely that Canadians, including the French-speaking ones, are _very aware of the wealth of French accents/varieties found around the globe_ because they have welcomed all those nationals. On a personal note, I myself was born and raised in a neighbourhood where people speak 50 different languages and I remember fondly a friend of mine from Côte-d'Ivoire in grade school, so yeah. The answer is imho outstanding & addresses the questions with practical considerations, shows knowledge and insight. I'm thankful for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer edit my answer, but on reflection, I should have added the websites phono.uqac.ca and tlfq.ulaval.ca to my list of references useful for learners.

Comment: Thanks to LPH and Eyla for your kind words.

Answer (score 3):

Since the differences, or lack thereof, have been thoroughly covered in other answers and comments, I'd like to focus on your middle question, namely whether your should study both.

Ultimately, only you can really answer that question, but here are things I'd consider if I were in your shoes:

1. Why do you want to study French?
2. Do you plan to use it for professional purposes?
3. Do you have any plans to live in a French-speaking country or region?
4. If you answered yes to the above, for how long?

If your answers boil down to something along the lines of a very nebulous "because it sounds cool, but I don't really know", then you're probably better off learning "international French", i.e. the basic set of vocabulary, syntax and grammar that is share by all varieties of French. You can then gradually pick up on more specific regional diversions as the need arises.

On the other hand, if the questions lead you to a very specific answer such as "I want to move to Montreal and work in the _____ industry", then you'll want to focus on studying the French Canadian variety of the language.

If you're still unsure, you probably can't go wrong if you simply start by getting a firm grounding in the basics of the language. You'll be able to build on that to adapt to any more specific needs you might have later.

Happy studying!

Answer (score 2):

The differences aren't that big. The major gap would be the accent and some of the expressions. There isn't two different languages to learn, that's just one, with some variations. It's just like British English and American English. You just need to learn French, in general, to be able to understand Canadian French, and general one.

Comment: Well differences are sometimes big enough that it makes it difficult for a French speaker even... At least I can have a hard-time understanding canadian French and there are enough differences that a whole book would be needed to list them all I think...

Comment: I guess it depends of the person. I've lived there for a year and half and haven't got any problem to understand anything. That was mostly regarding some of the expressions they were using, and sometimes prononciation of some of the words. Just as a British English person comparing his way to pronounce "herbs" and "aluminium" with an American person.

Comment: Well indeed I'm probably not hearing enough Canadian French so when it happens it sounds like a foreign language to me. Not like Chinese or Russian, but still. The accent may play a big role in the misunderstanding though. I think a French learner might have an even harder time to understand...

Comment: I agree on that. They might have kind à hard time understanding it. But fundamentally, what I meant is that it's not two separated langages. Like, when you go on a website, they oftentimes propose Canadian French and French as langages; when it actually has no difference at all when it comes to the way it's written. Just an example popping out my mind.

Comment: @Shozs Yes, you are considering the written, taught at school, standard French which is essentially the same language on both sides of the Atlantic while Laurent is considering spoken French which is significantly different from written French both in France and in Canada.

Comment: @jlliagre Not really what I'm considering. They're speaking the exact same language as we do. Except for the accent and some of their expressions. That's it. There's nothing more that differs.

Comment: Dans mon expérience - assez malheureuse je dois dire - je trouve que le français québecois est de plus en plus envahi par la structure de l'anglais et cela donne des phenomènes assez bizarres.  Pourtant, dans les domaines professionnels de la langue au Quebec, ils se montrent fort soucieux d'éviter la traduction litérale tout en ratant l'existence du problème au niveau de la structure. Moi, personellement, j'ai interprété pour des locuteurs canadiens sans aucun problème. C'est chouette le québecois. Et moi, je parle le français "hexagonal" toute en étant américaine...

Comment: @Shozs Of course this is all about French but there is no such thing as "speaking the exact same language" as far as linguistics is concerned. Individuals speak their own, unique variant of a language and this language might differ a lot depending on who they are talking to. Comparing two people ways of speaking is a multidimensional analysis about phonetics, syntax and vocabulary. A binary "same language/different language" is just an approximation.

Comment: It's a really close approximation then, if you're able to understand most of it. But I agree with what you said.

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Premièrement, vous pourrez constater que dans mon précédent commentaire j'écris "not like Chinese and Russian", ce qui est le contraire d'une comparaison. Ensuite je ne comprends pas cette agressivité, n'étant pas particulièrement actif ici je m'étonne que mes rares et assez ponctuelles interventions aient pu à ce point vous choquer. Je ne vois pas non plus le rapport entre mes commentaires et un quelconque vocabulaire "technique", et finalement, étant Belge, je ne me considère pas comme chauvin ou défenseur de la langue française. D'ailleurs je parle aussi le néerlandais...

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. j'ajouterais également que quand j'écris "it sounds like a completely foreign language to me", je met en évidence ma propre incapacité à comprendre ce sociolecte comme vous dites. Soit dit en passant, le fait que certains films soient doublés en québecquois ET en Francais "de France" semblerait aussi indiquer que ces 2 langues ont assez de différences pour mériter ce traitement... Mais soit, si j'ai tant de mal à comprendre votre sociolecte, ce doit être parce que je suis chauvin, fermé et rétrograde...

Comment: @LaurentS. Merci, et désolé pour ma réaction. Toutes les contributions sont les bienvenues. Je pense qu'on a des sensibilités différentes sur le sujet. La dernière question que j'ai posée montre que j'ai moi-même certaines interrogations avec certains éléments de mon basilecte, entre autres. Mais oui, je trouve blessantes ces comparaisons, même indirectes, avec des langues bien éloignées, ou l'affirmation qu'on comprend quasiment mieux l'anglais etc. On aimerait être compris. Je ne comprends pas spontanément un mélange d'argot avec le verlan, mais je reconnais le fait français. Sans rancune.

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. J'essaierai à l'avenir de modérer mes comparaisons. Il est vrai que tout en étant plus importante que la différence entre la Belgique et la France, celle entre ces 2 pays et le québec n'est quand-même pas comparable à une langue étrangère, et encore moins à l'écrit. Disons que ces différences (vocabulaire + accent) me paraissent néanmoins difficiles à appréhender pour quelqu'un apprenant le français, mais sans-doute n'est-ce là qu'une question d'immersion, comme souvent dans l'apprentissage d'une langue.

Comment: There **aren't** two different languages [grammar].

Answer (score 2):

Lots of really good answers, I'll just add known examples that are understood very differently between the two. They're often used in comedy sketches.

> Puis-je voir une photo de tes **gosses**? (Can I see a picture of your kids?)

Famous example, the original definition of *gosse* is kids, but in Quebec it means testicles. As you can see, you can only ask that in France.

> Ce repas est **écœurant**! (This meal is disgusting)

The meaning of *écœurant* is disgusting or nauseating, but in Quebec we use it as wonderful. The meaning is the complete opposite, so make sure you know what you're doing.

In addition, some words related to the structure of the system might differ. For example, *baccalauréat* (bachelor's degree): In France, you get it after high school but in Quebec it's the first degree of university.

---

We have a lot of weird slang and expressions in Quebec that might not be understood by people from France, but it doesn't prevent communication at all. It's not like we're going to use slang on purpose when talking to someone that doesn't originate from Quebec. Other than that, we study the same exact french at school so the written language is identical.

Answer (score 1):

*Wikipedia* makes balanced assertions on the topic, along the lines of the previous answers:

> Formal Quebec French uses essentially the same orthography and grammar
> as Standard French, with few exceptions, and exhibits moderate lexical
> differences. Differences in grammar and lexicon become more marked as
> language becomes more informal.
>
> While phonetic differences also decrease with greater formality,
> Quebec and European accents are readily distinguishable in all
> registers.[...]
>
> [ Wikipedia, [*Quebec French*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French#Relation_to_European_French) ]
>
> *Le français écrit du Québec est syntaxiquement identique au français
> européen et international. Il ne s'en distingue que marginalement sur
> le plan lexical. Quant au français oral (du Québec), passablement
> différent du français écrit (européen et international), il comporte
> des écarts syntaxiques et phonétiques parfois prononcés par rapport à
> la norme. Le québécois connaît des variétés régionales* [...]
>
> [ Wikipedia, [*Français québécois*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) ]

Generally, you learn the basics and as you use the language, exposure to a variety will do the rest. For some specific instances see also [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1139).