# La valeur démonstrative de l'article défini en français

Tags: articles

En anglais l'article défini (the) peut avoir la valeur d'un adjectif démonstratif (demonstrative determiner) ; voici un exemple typique de cette utilisation.

- It's a story that I wrote  recently  said she and I do not know it well enough  to make the most of it in a narration viva voce, specially from memory; moreover the art of story telling from memory is not my forte, I never gave much time to **the** activity.

On ne peut pas selon ce que je me rappelle d'une information glanée je ne sais plus où ni quand, traduire « the » (en gras) par « la » en français ; ce « the » a une valeur de démonstratif reconnue dans les grammaires assez avancées pour l'anglais et pour l'étude de l'anglais comme langue étrangère par l'étudiant français. La phrase est donc traduite comme suit.

- C'est une histoire que j'ai écrite récemment dit-elle et je ne la connais pas assez bien pour en tirer le maximum dans une narration de vive voix, en particulier si je dois faire cela de mémoire ; de plus l'art de raconter des histoires de vive voix n'est pas mon fort, je n'ai jamais donné beaucoup de temps à **cette** activité.

Il me semble avoir une quasi-certitude que l'on ne peut pas utiliser l'article défini de cette façon ; cependant une, ou plusieurs confirmations ne seraient pas inutiles; les questions sont donc les suivantes ;

1/ Est-ce que cette valeur démonstrative de l'article est reconnue en français français ? L'est-elle en français canadien ? (Répondre quand même si ce second élément manque)

2/ Si la réponse à la question précédente est que l'on n'attache pas à l'article en français français une valeur de démonstratif selon la manière exposée ci-dessus, répondre à ceci ; est-ce qu'il existe en France à l'heure actuelle, sous l'influence de l'anglais une tendance propre à la possible introduction de ce concept grammatical dans le français ? Une telle introduction parait-elle souhaitable généralement ? Est-elle souhaitable de votre point de vue individuel en tant que fournisseur d'une réponse à la présente question ?

Comment: Je suis quasiment certain que l'article défini n'a pas de valeur démonstrative, mais je ne sais pas comment "prouver" mon affirmation.

Comment: Il y a bon nombre de réponses qui sont basées sur l'expérience personnelle de leur auteur, je suis moi-même responsable de plusieurs telles réponses. Il est dommage que vous ne jugiez pas bon de hasarder cette opinion, mais cette quasi-certitude qui est la votre renforce la mienne au point que je ne doute déjà presque plus  ;

Comment: J'ai tenté d'écrire une question mais il n'y avait rien de plus que ce que tu as constaté dans ta question, je n'ai pas trouvé de façon de la tourner pour qu'elle apporte quelque chose.

Answer (score 2):

Pour répondre très (trop) brièvement à la question une : selon moi non mais je n'ai pas de source pour étayer cette (quasi) certitude...

Et pour la question deux : non plus ; c'est l'inverse qui se passe en français. Le déterminant **ce** [devient un article défini](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_2006_num_152_4_6638).

Pour finir, je ne pense pas que l'introduction de ce concept grammatical soit souhaitable en français. En anglais la généralité s'exprime sans article, en français avec un article. Si l'article peut soudainement prendre une valeur démonstrative beaucoup de phrases simples deviendraient difficiles à comprendre : *j'adore l'hiver*. Cet hiver ou tous les hiver?

Comment: C'est une réponse de plus dans le sens de confirmer cette supposition (commentaires, Teleportinggoat) ; le critère de  préservation de la clarté du langage est fondamental, mais il ne faut pas négliger que cet usage en anglais est contextuel et ne nuit pas à la clarté de l'anglais, sauf en cela qu'il le complique par la multiplication des fonctions pour cette forme (plus grande difficulté pour l'apprenant, tout d'abord).

Answer (score 1):

> — *Tiens, dit* LE *poussin en regardant du côté de la route, voilà un
>   bœuf*. ([AYMÉ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Aym%C3%A9), *Contes du chat perché*, Le cerf et le chien.) [Le
>   *personnage* a été présenté dans la phrase précédente.]
>  [...]
>  Dans l'exemple d'AYMÉ, l'article est assez proche du
>   démonstratif. De même, quand on désigne une réalité présente : *Oh !*
>   LE *beau papillon !* — ou un moment proche de celui où l'on parle :
>   *Nous partons à* L'*instant*.
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, Duculot, 14e, § 579,
>   incluant ce qui se trouve entre crochets ]

[CQFD](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/CQFD). Déniché en quelques instants dans une grammaire digne de ce nom.

---

Incidemment, dans certains cas l'emploi du démonstratif peut faire l'objet de critiques :

> Certains grammairiens critiquent comme un anglicisme ***ce pays***
>   s'il s'agit du pays du locuteur et de l'interlocuteur : *Si pour le
>   malheur de* CE *pays vous triomphez dimanche prochain* [aux élections]
>   (MAURIAC, dans *Mauriac avant Mauriac*, p. 47) [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, Duculot, 14e, § 617 a (fonction
>   *déictique* : localisation de l'objet par rapport au locuteur) ]

---

Dans certains autres cas, on a d'autres choix...

En fonction *cataphorique* (annonçant ce qui va suivre) quand le démonstratif annonce un infinitif prépositionnel ou une subordonnée conjonctive commençant par *que* (comme dans « *Ils jugent le problème automatiquement d'après* CE *principe, que la vérité est la nouveauté*. » (MONTHERLAND, *Célibataires*, p. 147), « la langue courante préfère aujourd'hui l'article défini. Mais le démonstratif est presque obligé dans certaines expressions comme *en ce sens que* [...], *rendre cette justice que* [...] : *Rendez-moi* CETTE *justice que j'ai offert à Genièvre de lui céder la place*. (MAURIAC, *Nœud de vipères*, I) » (LBU14 § 617 c, incluant les idées énoncées en début de paragrahes).

Il y a des cas où la valeur démonstrative du démonstratif est *atténuée*, par exemple dans un cas où il « présente un substantif accompagné d'une relative, parfois d'une épithète, d'un complément déterminatif. Dans la plupart des cas, l'article défini conviendrait aussi. [...] *Le peuple français a* [...] *posé au milieu même du vieux continent monarchique la première assise de* CET *immense édifice de l'avenir, qui s'appellera un jour les États-Unis d'Europe* » (HUGO, Actes et paroles, Avant l'exil, Nelson, p. 380) [1851] » (LBU14, § 618 a). On lire en détail tous ces articles pour davantage de nuances si on désire comparer avec le [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language).

---

Par ailleurs « le français écrit du Québec est syntaxiquement identique au français européen et international. Il ne s'en distingue que marginalement sur le plan lexical. » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) ; voir aussi [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23803)).

---

**En résumé** :

1. Oui, l'article défini peut se rapprocher du démonstratif chez les     meilleurs auteurs et oui, puisqu'il s'agit de la même langue.
2. Ne s'applique pas vu la réponse en 1). Personnellement, ça me semble être le dernier des soucis quand on intercale des mots anglais dans à peu près toutes les phrases, sur le vieux continent comme au Québec.

Comment: Je pense que dans l'exemple d'Aymé, l'article est entièrement déterminatif : le charactère du poussin a été présenté ; si ce n'est pas le cas, il me semble qu'il ne peut pas être question d'autre chose que d'un contexte imaginaire  (un contexte que l'auteur a choisi de laisser indéfini, qui sera précisé par la suite dans le récit (style reconnu, il me semble)) ; l'exemple du papillon est beaucoup plus difficile à dissocier de la  notion de tour démonstratif ; l'expression de routine, disons, est « Oh! Regarde **ce** beau papillon ! » ; (champ 1)

Comment: on sait très bien que le contexte matériel pour cet exemple est généralement celui d'une discrimination par indication gestuelle, omise dans certain cas en raison de l'apparente évidence du phénomène ; le remplacement par le déterminant résulte, sans aucun doute, en une forme courante ; cependant, précurseur de cette forme, se trouve la forme suivante,  moins usitée il me semble mais valide et utile, cette forme n'étant rien de plus que la forme citée (déterminant à la place du démonstratif) à laquelle est ajouté un complément de présentation ou d'introduction, (champ 2)

Comment: ou comme on voudra l'appeler : sur cette fleur, sur la grande fleur, qui s'en va là-bas,…Il n'est plus question de discrimination mais de détermination. Il n'y a qu'un pas pour analyser la phrase exclamative sans ce complément comme comportant un pur déterminant avec une ellipse du complément. Je dois ajouter que ces considérations d'une possible valeur de démonstratif sont limitées à des cas marginaux . Qu'en est-il de la phrase présentée dans la question ? Qu'en est-il de la langue courante ? (fin)