# Le « piton » de la « banque à piton(s) » ?

Tags: sens, histoire, québec, régionalismes

> — J'aimerais avoir vingt dollars s'il-te-plaît...
>  — Est-ce que
>   j'ai l'air d'une banque à piton(s) ?
>  
>   — Bien à quoi ça ressemble une *banque à piton(s)* ?

---

On entend généralement par là *une source inépuisable d'argent* ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/banque_%C3%A0_pitons)). [On sait](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20024) qu'on a une sémantique parallèle au Québec où le *piton* a familièrement la fonction du bouton (en plus des dérivés : *pitonner, pitonnage, pitonneux* etc.). Par ailleurs, au *Glossaire du parler français au Canada*, préparé par la Société du parler français du Canada, éd. *L'action sociale*, 1930, à la p. 520, on a à l'entrée *piton* différents sens plus ou moins inusités aujourd'hui... :

[image]

...dont ces références au jeton (3), particulièrement (4) qui ressemble à une forme de [*billet à ordre*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2083951) un peu comme la [*monnaie de carte*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monnaie_de_carte) à l'époque coloniale ; on a surtout historiquement des [cas](https://ajsaguenay.com/interpretation-historique) où au 19/20e des entreprises ont rémunéré leurs employés avec des [pitons échangeables](https://books.google.com/books?id=6rMNAAAAQAAJ&dq=De%20Peter%20%C3%A0%20%C2%AB%20Pitons%20%C2%BB&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q=De%20Peter%20%C3%A0%20%C2%AB%20Pitons%20%C2%BB&f=false) dans certains commerces précis, et [Arthur Buies](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Buies) parlait du prénom [*Peter* (McLeod)](http://www.biographi.ca/en/bio/mcleod_peter_8E.html) ([Fr](http://www.biographi.ca/fr/bio/mcleod_peter_8F.html)) de la maison [Price](http://www.biographi.ca/fr/bio/price_william_9F.html) comme de l'inspiration pour le mot piton en contexte (le bon échangeable) dans la région de Saguenay...

---

- De quel piton s'agit-il au juste dans l'expression *banque à piton(s)* au Québec ? Quel est le lien entre ce piton et la [*banque*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/banque/7863?q=banque#7820) ? Pourquoi pas *presse à billets*, *machine à imprimer de la monnaie*, *coffre-fort* ou *banque/banquier* tout court ?
- Connaît-on un jeu (de table, de société, de carte) ou un sport (sauf l'alpinisme) où on emploie un/des piton(s) ?

Comment: J'ai l'impression que tu tournes autour du pot. Un « piton » (celui de « Peter ») étant un ancêtre de la monnaie (bien plus pratique que d'échanger une demie-chèvre par exemple ou une vache si on caricature le troc), on retrouve dès lors concrètement l'utilisation d'une vieille expression historique de « banque à piton ». Afin de pouvoir échanger ces bons contre autre chose, il fallait bien un référencement et une sorte de banque, donc rien d'étrange ici.

Comment: @ On a eu: Excuse-moi si je n'ai pas été clair, j'ai vu ton message précédent et tu sembles t'être un peu emballé. Ce que je voulais dire c'est que je *pense* que pour ta première question, cela vient bien de l'origine de "Peter", comme on pourrait comprendre ajourd'hui « je ne suis pas un distributeur à billet » qui avec piton donnerait « je ne suis pas un distributeur à pitons », avec le sous-entendu que « banque » veut dire source inépuisable (on dit bien quand quelqu'un est "devenu soudainement riche" s'il n'a pas braqué une banque).

Comment: Je suis québécois, et quand on joue aux jeux vidéos ou on regarde la télévision, on dit pitonner. Les boutons sont bien souvent appelé grossièrement piton, et ce, même quand s'en n'est pas vraiment. Par exemple, le clavier virtuel de ton iphone, on appel ça des pitons quand même. "Arrête de pitonner sur ton téléphone" dit la mère à sa fille.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the singular “au jeu” (instead of “aux jeux” or “dans les/des jeux) in the parenthetical in *piton*’s meaning #2 (3?): “Jeton (pour marquer les points au jeu)” could be an indication that the *Glossaire* intended to include (perhaps even exclusively) the kinds of *jetons*, regardless of their shape, used to “keep score” in nearly all casino table gambling games. If this is the case, then “banques à piton(s)/[jeton(s)” could be referring to the vault/holding place for the seemingly unlimited wealth possessed by seemingly unbeatable casinos.

In English, the idea/dream of “[beating the] *casino*” is often captured with “[beating the] *house*” or “[beating the] **bank**” and, [according to these Reverso-context translations](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/beat+the+house) the French notions of “battre **la banque**” and [“faire sauter **la banque**”](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=faire+sauter+la+banque&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en) also exist in gambling contexts.

Just as you mention/wonder in your question, however, the above doesn’t explain why just “banque” or “banquier” all alone wouldn’t work?
 Personally I think either of them alone would work just fine, but maybe the addition of “à piton(s),” whether it’s referring to gambling jetons as I’ve suggested above or to “pitons échangeables,” as you suggest in the question, is serving to emphasize the notion of “[your **private**] bank/[your **private**] banker,” which notion of “private” is often included in the English “I’m not your private bank/er” to respond negatively to requests for money.

Regarding the use of “pitons” (only the nail-shaped ones, aka “pegs”) in games, for one where they’re used solely for “keeping score” (pour marquer les points), there’s [cribbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cribbage) (as described by *Wikipedia*) and for games where *piton*-like pegs are actually part of the game, [here’s a link to *BoardGameGeek.com*](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/44692/games-pegs-and-holes) that lists a few, including  “Hounds and Jackals: Game of the Pharaohs,” “Peg Baseball,” and my favorite, “Battleship.”

Comment: Thanks, this feels a lot like the _tirelire_ with the spin of a broader storage facility, or even the _croupier_ in a way. It's possible there was an influx of English language elements because of the Price story and industrial lumber and the fact that _piton_  was quite usual a word ; there is also that general pronunciation similarity between piton and Peter. The crib is also well known here that I know of. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

"Une banque à pitons" est une manière de dire "une banque actionnée par des boutons" donc un guichet automatique. Le mot "piton" au Québec signifie "bouton-poussoir", donc un bouton sur lequel on appuie (et qui a un effet), par opposition avec "bouton de chemise", par exemple.

Comment: Bonjour ! Merci, mais comme vous le voyez aussi dans la [question liée](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/20024/3177), je suis familier avec l'emploi dans le sens du _bouton_, et oui c'est à l'origine de plus d'une expression avec _piton_ au Québec. Mais la _banque à pitons_ participe-t-elle vraiment de ce piton-là ; en passant on m'a déjà servi la locution avant que n'apparaissent les guichets automatiques alors de quel bouton s'agissait-il auparavant ?? Si vous avez une source ou d'autres précisions, n'hésitez pas à enrichir votre réponse ! Merci !